# VBA Code closes my separate .Net Winform App?

Tags: .net, winforms, ms-access, vba

The below code is the close routine of an **Access App** our **BA** wrote.  When executed it is not only closing the **Access App** but my **C# winform app** as well, on the same computer.  The Access app is named **DME Referral** and my winform app main process runs in the Task Manager as **MATRIX.exe**.*(Yes I am programming the MATRIX...never allow a group of Social Workers and Nurses to name your program!)*

I do not do much with **Access(VBA)** programming so I am hoping someone here can help.

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdClose_Click

Call ToggleVisible

DoCmd.Quit

Exit_cmdClose_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdClose_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdClose_Click

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleVisible()
    Me.txtLastNameCrit.Visible = False
    Me.txtFirstNameCrit.Visible = False
    Me.cmdSearch.Visible = False

    Me.cmbCoor.Visible = False
    Me.cmdSearchByCoor.Visible = False

    Me.txtStartDate.Visible = False
    Me.txtEndDate.Visible = False
    Me.cmdDMEReport1.Visible = False       
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to get this from the BA now.

Comment: It takes you to an ActiveX library.  No code though.

Comment: From memory in Access, DoCmd.Quit is a built-in to exit the app. You might try using Spy++ to watch the window of your C# app to see (if) anyone is sending it a WM_QUIT or whatever.

Comment: Your code seems very odd to me. Why are you hiding controls on the form before closing the application? Also, I think having an error handler wrapped around DoCmd.Quite is problematic -- seems to me your error handler should be in the code you're calling, i.e., ToggleVisible (though there's little can go wrong with that at runtime). One small thing: I use Application.Quit instead of DoCmd.Quit. If you type Quit into the Immediate Window in Access and hit F1 to get the help, you'll find that DoCmd.Quit is deprecated in favor of Application.Quit, even though they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoCmd.Quit` should be just closing the MS Access portion; it's pretty standard.

I'm willing to be that one of two things are happening.
1) Focus has switched over to the C# winform app, and it's catching a signal to close. In this case, we can explicitly set the focus back to the MS Access form.  You can do that with `Me.SetFocus`.
Or
2) The C# winform app. is being launched from withing MS Access; and when the parent application is closed, the child is as well. In this case we may have to change the way the C# winform app. is launched. Does it close down as well when you manually close MS Access (click the 'X' on the top right corner)?